# How can cookies dictionary be made compatible with session.cookies

Tags: python

I am trying to collect cookies from a new requests.session() instance and then pass the cookies from that session to a cookie jar of a different session. Below is the cookie dictionary which I am trying to set as a cookie jar. Apparently the type of other accepted cookie jar files is below.

```
cookie_dict = {'cookie_a': 'foo', 'cookie_b': 'bar'}
```

Here's how I've been using the cookie jar...

```
session = requests.session()
jar = requests.cookies.RequestsCookieJar()
jar.set('cookie_c','blah') 
jar.set('cookie_d','blahh')
jar.set('cookie_e','blahhh')
jar.set('cookie_f','blahhh')
session.cookies = jar
print(type(jar))

output: <class 'requests.cookies.RequestsCookieJar'>
```

I'm trying to convert the dictionary (which is type dict) to the acceptable type required by session.cookies (appears to be type of the output above). Ideally, I'd like to just say

```
session.cookies = cookie_dict
```

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the cookie dictionary and then call the values associated with each key. For example

```
jar.set('cookie_c',cookie_dict['cookie_a'])
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you could always iterate through the dict.keys() and assign the values that way

Answer (score 1):

```
For i in dict.keys():
     cookie_value = dict[i]
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a python docs page discussing cookie setting in more depth: https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.cookies.html